# Pop out navigational menu

Tags: css

Having created drop-down menus in the past, I didn't think it would be that difficult to change the code to make a "pop-out" menu, but I haven't been able to get my second set of list items to appear horizontally. I have specified:

```
#nav li li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
```

but the list items are still displaying vertically. The code can be found in its entirety at http://www.durapropainting.com/draft/index.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#nav ul li ul{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 170px;
    top: 180px;
    z-index: 1000 !important;
    width: 400px;
} 

#nav ul li ul li{
    background-color: #F8981D;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: That didn't make my list items display horizontally.

Comment: I don't want the entire list to be displayed horizontally to the link, I want each list item to be displayed horizontally:  Item 1 Item 2, not: Item 1 <linebreak> Item 2

Comment: add enough width for '#nav ul li ul'

Answer (score 0):

```
#nav ul li
```

Select your selecta wisely?

Also its parent container is a vertical div, you need to move it out of that container to get any further

Edit:

```
#pop li a {display: inline;}
```

Comment: That is why I added "position: absolute;" to the second <ul> element (so it would be out of the container).

Comment: Dude, none of your selectors are matching it, that or I'm looking at the wrong page. The position is relative, of the ul and the li are display: list-item

Comment: Line 160 in the CSS is where I positioned the second <ul> absolutely.

Comment: Gotya, I was looking at the entire ul, not the sub ul.

The problem is that your A's are display block, add #pop li a{display: inline; }

Comment: That definitely changed the formatting, but still isn't displaying the list items horizontally.